# Update and Create Problem with Adding Columns to an Existing External Content Type in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, bcs, external-content-type

I used SharePoint Designer 2010 to create an external content type (ECT) that consumes and writes data to SQL Server. [Went through the process of connecting to a database table, then right-clicking the table created All Operations. Published to Sharepoint and everything is working well.

Now I am required to modify the original database, which is to add an additional field. After adding the new database field I need a way to be able to REFRESH my entire BCS so that the new field from the database shows up on the on the Create, Read Item, Update, Delete, and Read List form.  Inside each operation I’ve checked off the new field to be included in the operation, clicked finish and saved.   In the SharePoint site I opened the Modify View tab and included the new field and it does display correctly.  However, I’ve found that when I go to create or update an item that field does not show.

How can I get these fields to propagate throughout SharePoint in their respected operations?  I would hope there would be a way to do this without recreating the ECT.  I haven’t tried this yet might attempt soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been seeing the same issue.  When you update the data source and the corresponding operations on the ECT, everything works fine, EXCEPT the list forms.  You'll need to delete and recreate the list to have the forms updated.

Since the data does not reside in SharePoint you should not have to fear losing your data.  (No warranties express or implied though - test it in a staging environment first )

You should not, however, have to recreate the ECT. That will update fine if you update the operations.

Comment: Thank you so much, we're kind of new to the Sharepoint system at my copmany (exploring it right now), and this was one of the problems we were running into! Thank you for the help. Will keep this for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually recreate just the list forms without recreating the entire list.  In Sharepoint designer, delete the original New form, ususally called "NewForm.aspx", then create a new "New" form, also called "NewForm.aspx".  Any new columns will now be visible on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have edited the ECT in SPD 2010.  You don't need to delete the external list and recreate it.  Just modify the list view in SP and add the additional columns to the view.